# log4j2: custom formating for pattern parameter

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Usually logging looks like this:

```
Duration duration = ...;
log.info("Duration: {}", duration);
```

But what do if you need custom formatting?

```
if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    String value = duration.toSeconds() + "." + duration.toMillis();
    log.info("Duration: {}", value);
}
```

In this case code is complicated. I'm looking for a way to do simple logging as in first sample but to be able to customize value formatting using some mechanism, e.g, define a format function  for given type:

```
LogSystem.install(Duration.class, duration -> {
    return String.format("%d.%d", duration.toSeconds(), duration.toMillis();
});
```

Questions:

- does log4j 2.x have such or similar feature?
- may be it exists in other logging libraries?
- if no, can `if (log.isInfoEnabled()) { ... }` be simplified somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> does log4j 2.x have such or similar feature?

Yes, you can use

```
log.info("Duration: {}.{}", duration.toSeconds(), duration.toMillis());
```

You can pass as many parameters as you like. If you use parameterized logging, you don't need to check log.isInfoEnabled().

> may be it exists in other logging libraries?

SLF4j also supports parameterized logging.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need to do `duration.toSeconds(), duration.toMillis()` **in every log statement**. Yes, it can be extracted to some method... but it looks ugly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using the properties file.Set policies pattern in your log4j2.properties file like:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ABClog/ABCapplication.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ABClog/ABCapplication.%d{dd-MMM}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = { [%-5level %d{dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS } ] [%msg] }%n
```

After setting the above configuration in your log4j2.proerties file, you will get your desired output, even using properties file concept you can add extra info too e.g. Correlation-ID

```
log.info("hello")
```

Log4j2 document for more pattern style: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html